# How to include email recipient information in intents on Android 12?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-12

Ive been using the [recommended way](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email) to populate an email intent since the early days of Android. This includes recipient, subject, and body text.

On Android 12 however - the recipient field is always left out when doing this, everything else works exactly the same.

Whats is the issue here? Is this a bug in the OS? Im testing with gmail by default, but the same thing applies to other email clients, still only on Android 12.

```
private fun createIntent(
    metadata: String
): Intent {
    val uri = Uri.parse("mailto:")

    return Intent(ACTION_SENDTO)
        .setData(uri)
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_EMAIL,
            arrayOf("example@gmail.com") //Ive also tried without arrayOf, no difference.
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Feedback"
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_TEXT,
            metadata
        )
}
```

Comment: And ACTION_SEND ?

Comment: @blackapps It says (in the link above) that ACTION_SEND should be used when including an attachment. No attachment = ACTION_SENDTO. Edit: I still tested this, no app is able to handle the intent using ACTION_SEND.

Comment: Try putting the email address in the `Uri` (`mailto:example@gmail.com`).

Comment: EmailAddressExposedException? ;-)

Comment: @CommonsWare This works, kind of.. Recipient is now included, but all the other fields are omitted instead.

Comment: Hmmmm... you could try `subject` and `body` URL-style parameters for `EXTRA_SUBJECT` and `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: I couldnt get that working @CommonsWare, but I did stumble upon another solution - please see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `ACTION_SEND` in combination with the `selector` block does the trick. This works across all API levels down to API 21. Ill let someone else explain why that is, but the important thing is that it works.

```
private fun createIntent(
    metadata: String
): Intent {
    return Intent(ACTION_SEND)
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_EMAIL,
            arrayOf(EMAIL)
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            TITLE
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_TEXT,
            metadata
        )
        .apply {
            selector = Intent(ACTION_SENDTO).setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))
        }
}
```