# What is the reason of Android 12 ACTION_SENDTO intent extra anomaly?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-12

In Android 12 if you add informations as *subject*(`EXTRA_SUBJECT`) and *message*(`EXTRA_TEXT`) when you use `ACTION_SENDTO` Intent to send a text email, these don't appear in the email client message, contrarely to all previous versions.

An user in a similar [Kotlin question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796290/how-to-include-email-recipient-information-in-intents-on-android-12) seems has solved the problem using apply selector in this way:

```
private fun createIntent(
    metadata: String
): Intent {
    return Intent(ACTION_SEND)
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_EMAIL,
            arrayOf(EMAIL)
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            TITLE
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_TEXT,
            metadata
        )
        .apply {
            selector = Intent(ACTION_SENDTO).setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))
        }
}
```

What is the reason of this issue? What is the proper way to fix the issue in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> these don't appear in the email client message, contrarely to all previous versions

How apps handle inbound extras is up to the developers of the apps. And, since [`ACTION_SENDTO` is not documented to have those extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SENDTO), you should not be surprised when apps ignore those extras.

> What is the proper way to fix the issue in Java?

Do what you have there in Kotlin, if `ACTION_SEND` will work for you. `Intent` works the same way whether you use it in Java, Kotlin, or any other suitable programming language. Your selector will limit your `Intent` to apps that have activities that support that `mailto:` `Uri` for `ACTION_SENDTO` (which may be more than just email apps).

By eyeball, the Java equivalent should be something like this:

```java
private Intent createIntent(String metadata) {
    Intent result = new Intent(ACTION_SEND)
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { EMAIL }
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            TITLE
        )
        .putExtra(
            EXTRA_TEXT,
            metadata
        );
        
    result.setSelector(new Intent(ACTION_SENDTO).setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")));
       
    return result;
}
```